# Unable to run query: ?? No query error message leads me nowhere

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

SO I have this authentication code. Everything else works except when I input a wrong user name. It just keeps showing in the page: "Unable to run query:" <-- Only this. I don't know what's wrong. Please do help.

Here's my code for that part:

```
if($UserN){
    if($UserP){
        require("connect.php");

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE UserName = '$UserN'");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query) or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());

        if($numrows == 1){
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error()); // fetch associated: get function from a query for a database
            $dbpass = $row['PassWord']; // read password of inputted user from the query.
            $dbuser = $row['UserName']; // read username from the query
            $dbactive = $row['Active']; // read if user is active
            $dbid = $row['CustNum'];

            if($UserP == $dbpass){
                if($dbactive == 1){
                //set session information
                $_SESSION['CustNum'] = $dbid;
                $_SESSION['UserName'] = $dbuser;

                echo "<br><br><center><b>You have been logged in as <b>$dbuser</b>. <a href='orderform.php'>Click here</a> to go to the member page.</b></center><br><br>";
                }
                else
                    echo "$form <center><b>You need to activate your account.</b></center></br>";
            }
            else
                echo "$form <center><b>You did not enter a correct password.</b></center> </br>";
        }
        else
            echo "$form <center><b>The username you entered was not found.</b></center></br> ";

        mysql_close();
    }
    else
        echo "$form <center><b>You must enter your password. </b></center></br>";
}
else
    echo "$form <center><b>You must enter your username. </b></center></br>";
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection here: `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE UserName = '$UserN'");`

Comment: Better hope Little Bobby Tables never tries to log in.

Comment: This is **extremely** unsafe and should not be exposed to the general public. An [automatic SQL vulnerability testing tool](http://sqlmap.org/) would have a field day with this. It's only a matter of time until you're hacked if you have code like this.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be that `mysql_num_rows()` returns 0 in case of an invalid username.

You could adapt your code like this:

```
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows === FALSE)
    die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());
if ($numrows === 0) {
    echo "User not found!";
}
```

Note the use of `===` to test whether `mysql_num_rows()` has returned 0 or FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

```
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query) or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());
```

If your query returns 0 rows, then the first part of this will evaluate to false. That will then trigger the `die()`.

Answer (score 0):

change this line `if($numrows == 1){` to `if( $numrows !== FALSE && $numrows >= 1 ){` as you want the conditional check to pass, if there is any resultset returned.

Or, if there's always gonna be only 1 record returned, then `if( $numrows !== FALSE && $numrows === 1 ){`